# Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1 while compiling a Vue NativeScript project

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, nativescript

I am new to vue-nativescript, on trying to try my first app trial I get the following error.

```
info: Bundling application for android...

Webpack is watching the files…

Executing post-build scripts
info: Running NativeScript application...
Searching for devices...
Skipping prepare.
Building project...
Gradle build...
Unable to apply changes on device: 3300369ecaaa23b3. Error is: Command 
gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.
```

I am using NativeScript 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `multiDexEnabled true` to your app.gradle file, like this:

```
android {  
      defaultConfig {  
            generatedDensities = []
            multiDexEnabled true
            applicationId = XXX
      }  
}
```